# What was this red deep sky object?

Tags: naked-eye

I was looking through sky yesterday and saw something red in sky (naked eye ) like nebula or something then tried using stellarium and mobile observatory apps to find out what it was, But couldnt find anything like this in them. I also tried to capture it on my phone but nothing visible except brightest stars.

I just know it was in cygnus - vulpecula - sagitta or somewhere near it.

As i wear glasses and dont have access to dark sky, it was my first naked eye view of some sort of deep sky object. Ill become so happy if i find what that red object was.

Comment: Why do you describe it as a "deep sky object" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving light in night sky](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/moving-light-in-night-sky)

Comment: It is technically possible to deduce the date for *yesterday* from the date you posted, but it would be helpful to future readers if you [edit]ed in the actual date.

Comment: Why do you write *nebula*? Did it have a size relative to (other) stars?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no deep sky objects (or extended objects) that show any color to the naked eye. They are too faint to activate the color sensors, so they appear white. I think you saw something nonastronomical.

You will have a better idea the next time you see it; get a better estimate of its location so that you can find it on a star chart. Use binoculars if you have them.

Comment: It didnt move at all was higher than expected and no buildings where in that directions, just water. Was bigger than other stars. I dont think i can go there for a long time....